# DRF Simple JWT "No active account found with the given credentials"

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am attempting to get the access and refresh JWT tokens using `djangorestframework-simplejwt`.
I tried to hit the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/` endpoint with POST method, sending username and password as request data on Postman, but the response is `"detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"` with 401 Unauthorized error code. I've also done ran `python manage.py createsuperuser`, but the error still raises.

Here is the following `settings.py` file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'drf_spectacular',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'corsheaders',
]

from datetime import timedelta

...

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=1),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'username',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
}

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    "DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema",
}
```

User Serializer at serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = [
            'user_id',
            'username',
            'email',
            'password',
            'date_created',
        ]
```

User model at models.py :

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

User registration view at views.py :

```
class UserRegister(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=user, context = {'request':request})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user_saved = serializer.save(password=make_password(user['password']))
            return Response(user_saved,
                status=200)
        return Response({
            "error" : "Error encountered"},
            status=406)
```

And the urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
    path('api/token/refresh/', TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem rises because the class `default_user_authentication_rule(user)` **returns user if the user is not none and the user has is_active true state**. The class is available within `authentication.py` file inside `rest_framework_simplejwt` library. The class is written as follows :

```
def default_user_authentication_rule(user):
    # Prior to Django 1.10, inactive users could be authenticated with the
    # default `ModelBackend`.  As of Django 1.10, the `ModelBackend`
    # prevents inactive users from authenticating.  App designers can still
    # allow inactive users to authenticate by opting for the new
    # `AllowAllUsersModelBackend`.  However, we explicitly prevent inactive
    # users from authenticating to enforce a reasonable policy and provide
    # sensible backwards compatibility with older Django versions.
    return user is not None and user.is_active
```

The issue has been solved by added is_active column in Users model as follows :

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

and set DRF Simple JWT variable `'USER_ID_FIELD'` to `'username'` as follows :

```
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    ...
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'username',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',
```

then run `python manage.py makemigrations` followed by `python manage.py migrate` to apply Users model changes.

Comment: That's not recommended. Do not set the USER_ID_FIELD without read the documentation first: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#user-id-field